# Suppressing fields in bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm new to LaTeX and am using TeXstudio for compiling my documents. I'm using
    `\usepackage{natbib}`     for bibliography. The reference file was imported from EndNote for bibtex in `.txt` format - I changed the file extension to `.bib`

The citations work fine but there are a lot of fields in the references I don't want appearing in my document. All of them have the keywords, copyright info., ISBN diplayed in the reference section. I changed the reference style -
    `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}`    -hoping it would solve the problem but it's not working.

I checked a lot of answers on this website and elsewhere but they talk about, what I find to be, advanced stuff - often a different package is being used. Is there a simple way for removing unwanted fields?

Also I used 
    `\def\bibfont{\footnotesize}` for changing the font size but it also reduced the size for the heading 'References'. Can it be fixed?

And finally, I get an error sometimes that the `.bib` file does not have info in the author-name format. It works fine but every now and then when I open the file again, it gives me this error.

Answer (score 4):

With your current settings you have to edit your bib file by hand.

---

The standard packages doesn't interact well with the `bib`-file. The compilation `bibtex` produces an new bbl file where the complete `thebibliography` environment is saved.

As in other questions/answers I suggest switching to `biblatex`. This packages allows you a better interaction between the the bib fields and the output. The switching is really simple and describes in various answers. One of the best is:

- [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex)

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the previous answer that says you have to manually edit the bib file or switch to biblatex.

I use natbib with the style "apalike" and it works just fine in displaying only the needed fields.

I tried to use \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN} and that worked too: only some fields are displayed (e.g. it doesn't display keywords).

However, I noticed when I switched from one style to the other, the bibliography didn't change immediately.
So you might need to re-compile your document a few times or delete the various output files to ensure that everything is compiled again.
(I'm somewhat new to Latex too and I don't use TexStudio)

Anyway, you **can** get only the IEEEtranN fields displayed using natbib.

Comment: The only reason that they are not displayed is that they are not defined. But how can you suppress a field?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment.
Using a style, you make only certain fields appear in your reference section. That's what the user wanted: showing some fields  and no others. What am I missing?

Comment: Not missing. I mean your style solves the requirements. But the style doesn't allow suppressing fields like `url` or `number`.

Comment: I assume that he uses IEEEtranN style because he wants IEEEtranN fields. 
If he wants to suppress fields that are included in IEEEtranN (like  url), then he'd have to find a different style OR create a new style - possibly by modifying the IEEEtranN one (not sure how this is achieved though).

Comment: (infact he expected IEEEtranN to solve his issues and the unwanted fields listed - keywords, copyright, ISBN - are not part of IEEEtranN. Therefore, I think that he had some problems in using IEEEtranN, like the "compilation problem" I had when switching from apalike to IEEEtranN )