# BIBTEX not BIBLATEX: Suppress fields in bibliography -- any updates?

Tags: bibtex

I have the same question as:

- [Suppressing fields in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118308/suppressing-fields-in-bibliography)
- [Omitting unwanted bibtex information from bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263355/omitting-unwanted-bibtex-information-from-bibliography)?

Any updates as on MacTeX 2019?

I am asking a simple way to suppress fields provided in bst, but not by manually modifying entries in bib files.

Please note:

- I would like to use bibtex and not biblatex, at least for the particular paper I am working on right now, wanting to use jecon.bst. No advice thus is necessary to switch to biblatex. (Though I am not particularly good, I am already using biblatex to some extent in other occasions.)
- I am asking whether there is a simple method like adding options in the preamble.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In general there is no simple setting in the preamble you could use. If you are using BibTeX there are essentially two strategies: (1) Modify the `.bib` file. This doesn't have to happen manually. You could for example use `bibtool` or Biber's `--tool` mode. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415007/35864. (2) Modify the `.bst` file to ignore certain fields. This is pretty much what the second part of Alan's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263392/35864 does.

Comment: Very few `.bst` files offer an additional option for customisation via control entries in the `.bib` file. Some have a few simple function definitions at the beginning for customisation. But it is unlikely that any of that would help you in removing fields.

Comment: it is usually fairly simple to modify a copy of the bst bibtex style but the details depend on the style and which field you want to drop.

Comment: Is your issue solved? How? Have you considered to use `biblatex`? You can `biblatex` ciustomize very easy, there are commands for that. An bibtex style is not easy to be cutomized ...